# Java Parsing String for value after

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a string that contains a "table name" that I would like to extract out of this string.  Basically from this string below, I would like to just grab "test_table".  The String always designates "Table name=", but I am having trouble with walking this string and pulling out the table name that I need.

I need to grab each char until I hit the comma, but I am having trouble.  An example string looks like this:

```
{newModel=Table name=test_table, nameInSource=null, uuid=tid:f1f46c57b618-b9a0d09f-00000001}model
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: have you tried some code? Paste it.

Comment: You can try to parse that into key/value like or just  go and force it using the pattern that you know, indexOf "Table name=" and get the value to the next indexOf ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression with a matching group around the part you want.  The example below looks for the substring `Table name=` in the target string then captures every character until it finds a comma in the group numbered one.  Finally, if the pattern was found then it returns the characters in group one or "null".

```java
public static String parseTableName(String s) {                             
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Table name=([^,]*)");                        
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);                                                 
  return m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;                                      
}                                                                           

// ...
parseTableName(yourString); // => "test_table"
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? There are a couple of approaches:

You could use a regex to match the key=value pattern to pull it out that way.

You could also just use JSON which is more standard to parse (plenty of libraries to do that).

You could strip out the characters `{ , }` and do a string split on `=`

Comment: I had originally used an indexOF but had not used the regex pattern that Maerics posted below.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample it actually looks like the key your looking for is "name" not "Table name" (where "Table" is the value of the previous "newModel" key.  In any case, there are many ways to do this in Java.  Assuming you don't know the order of keys/values in the string, I would use the StringTokenizer to split it up by commas, and then cycle through each key to see which is "name", and then use

```
String tableName;

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in, ","); 
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) { 
    String myString= st.nextToken();
    if (myString.startsWith("name") {
        tableName=myString.substr(myString.charAt("="), myString.length()+2); 
    }
    break;
}
```